# Display images inline in bootstrap col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i'm using Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 and i would like to display 3 images inline

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 text">
  <p>with some text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-8 screens">
    <img class="img-fluid first" src="{{asset('/images/project/screen-1.png')}}" alt="First screen">
    <img class="img-fluid main" src="{{asset('/images/project/screen-main.png')}}" alt="Main screen">
    <img class="img-fluid second" src="{{asset('/images/project/screen-2.png')}}" alt="Second screen">  
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried everything changing display options on .screens and on images and i'm out of ideas..

Comment: Did you try applying CSS to it i.e display:flex ?

Comment: Yes and it displays displays it in a line but it also stretches them.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of responsive images, the image(s) need an individual container that they can be sized into. In the example you have, there are three images in the one container, so they won't adapt individually to that single container. You could try something like:

```css
.row li {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}

img {
  border: 0 none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="small-img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 center">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive inline-block" alt="Responsive image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive inline-block" alt="Responsive image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive inline-block" alt="Responsive image" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```